# How to create components from an external data source in Tridion 2011

Tags: database, content-porter-2009

How to create components based on an external data source (SQL Server or Excel) in Tridion 2011?  In 5.3, I used to use Content Porter.  Apparently the feature no longer exists in Content Porter 2009 SP1.

Answer (score 8):

As Nuno says, this feature is not in there. I've not tried using the old Content Porter.

An alternative approach using Excel and the CoreService is described here by Ryan Durkin: http://blog.building-blocks.com/creating-custom-pages-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011

This involves a lot more code than your previous approach with Content Porter though.

Comment: Rob, thanks for the reply.  It's sad that importing data via API seems only option now.

Answer (score 4):

This feature was dropped from Content Porter when CP 2009 was released. I *think* you can still use the old Content porter for this, since it relies on the Business Connector which is still available in Tridion (but deprecated on Tridion 2013).

Initially there was a separate install for Content Porter 2.x that included only this feature, support may be able to provide you with that - but I'm pretty sure it wasn't tested to work with Tridion 2011.

Comment: Nuno, thank you. Apparently you cannot connect to Tridion 2011 CMS from Content Porter 2.x.